# How do I enable scrolling with mouse wheel in Ubuntu 12.10 running in Win 8 Hyper-V?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, hyper-v, scrolling

I created a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.10 on it in Hyper-V on Windows 8. I have a Logitech mouse with a scroll wheel that works fine when I'm not in the virtual machine. Is there a way to enable it in my virtual Ubuntu machine? I've been clicking and dragging on the scroll bars and it's getting old.

Comment: Have you updated the drivers within ubuntu?

Comment: I have run software update in Ubuntu. Are there other places where I would update the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions in the following module to enable to needed modules: http://baudlabs.com/how-to-install-hyper-v-integration-services-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

They are part of the Linux kernel now and just need to be enabled.

Comment: Did this work for everyone?  I see the services running but alas, still no mouse scroll.

Comment: Modules enabled, still no mouse wheel :(.

Comment: Yeah I agree.  I have one vm where it is working, but a newer one where the modules are enabled and still no mouse wheel.  Have not figured out why yet.